# Why do my localStorage not work with JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

I have started programming a ToDo list, but I can't save the values of the todos. I can save how much todos are there and then I can them get back, but it shows me only the value `[object HTML collection]`. I have done it with the `JSON.stringify()` function, and then in the local storage and for retrieve the todos I used `JSON.parse`. I have tried it on many different ways, but it won't work. Can anybody help me?

```
function save(){
    var alle = document.getElementById("liste");
    var inhalt = alle.querySelectorAll("p");
    var inhalte = document.getElementsByClassName("text");
    var speichern = JSON.stringify(inhalte);


    i = 0;
    while(i < inhalt.length){
        localStorage.setItem("Todo", speichern);
        i = i+1;
    };

};

function Aufrufen(){
    var inhalte = document.getElementsByClassName("text");
    var abrufen = localStorage.getItem("Todo");
    var obiekt = JSON.parse(abrufen);
    var alle = document.getElementById("liste");
    var inhalt = alle.querySelectorAll("p");
    var anzahl = Object.keys(obiekt).length;
    var i=0;

    while(i < anzahl) {
        var alle = document.getElementById("liste");
        var zeigen = document.getElementById("zeigen");
        var aktiv = document.getElementById("aktiv");
        var deaktiv = document.getElementById("deaktiv");
        var todo = document.createElement("p");
        var löschen = document.createElement("button");
        var text = document.createElement("input");
        var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
        var textlöschen = document.createTextNode("X");
        var obiekt = JSON.parse(abrufen);

        todo.className="todo";
        checkbox.type = "checkbox";
        checkbox.className="box";
        text.type="text";
        text.className="text";
        löschen.className="löschen";
        text.value=obiekt[i];

        alle.appendChild(todo);
        todo.appendChild(checkbox);
        todo.appendChild(text);
        todo.appendChild(löschen);
        löschen.appendChild(textlöschen);

        i=i+1;
        offen=offen+1;
        document.getElementById("offen").innerHTML = offen;

        löschen.addEventListener("click", function(){
            var parent = document.getElementById("liste");
            parent.removeChild(todo);
            if((checkbox.checked)==false){offen=offen-1;
            document.getElementById("offen").innerHTML = offen;}
        });

        checkbox.addEventListener("click", function(){
                var todotext = this.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("text").item(0);
                if((this.checked)==true){
                    todotext.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
                    offen=offen-1;
                    document.getElementById("offen").innerHTML = offen;
                    if(x==1){this.parentElement.style.display = "none"}
                }

                else if((this.checked)==false){
                    todotext.style.textDecoration = "none";
                    offen=offen+1;
                    document.getElementById("offen").innerHTML = offen;
                    if(x==2){this.parentElement.style.display = "none"}
                }
        }); 

    };
};
```

Comment: Share relevant HTML here

Comment: You can't serialize a HTMLColletion object.

Comment: I may be wrong, but `löschen` is probably invalid as a variable name, isn't it? (this is probably not related to the main issue itself)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach towards solving the problem is incorrect. You are trying to save the selected DOM elements to localstorage.

Instead,

1. select the DOM element.
2. Read its text contents.
3. Save the text contents to array.
4. Stringify the array
5. Save the array to localStorage.

Code for reading text content

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
x[0].innerHTML //Contains the text value which you can use
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> var inhalte = document.getElementsByClassName("text");
> var speichern = JSON.stringify(inhalte);
> ```

You are trying to convert a live HTMLCollection into a string.

Look what happens when you do that:

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("foo");
var json = JSON.stringify(inputs);
console.log(json);
```

```html
<input class="foo"><input class="foo"><input class="foo"><input class="foo">
```

There is no useful information in there.

You need to extract the data you need and put it into a sensible data structure.

For example, you might loop over some input elements and create an array of their values (and then pass that array through `JSON.stringify`)

When you read the JSON and go back the other way, you'll need to generate the HTML elements from the data.